# Запуск python как фонового процесса

Tags: python, bash, gnu-screen, nohup

Есть скрипт на python, и я хочу запустить его в фоне. Но ни nohup, ни screen мне не помогают, потому что после выхода из сессии скрипт перестает работать.
Пробовал:

```
nohup python3 main.py
nohup python3 main.py &
sudo nohup python3 main.py
sudo nohup python3 main.py &
```

Но при выходе из консоли nohup перестает работать. И logout, exit не работают. Выходил из nohup как через Ctrl+C, так и Ctrl+Z.

Попробовал screen. Создал окно, отвязал,

```
There is a screen on:
    24101.pts-0.server     (03/31/2020 02:15:30 PM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-user.
```

но после выхода из системы все окна очищаются, просто их нет больше, и screen -ls показывает

```
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-user.
```

Что я делаю не так? Это Astralinux (читать Debian)

Comment: а вы уверены, что скрипт не отработал полностью? Я постоянно пользуюь минимум двумя указанными у вас способами (`screen` &  `nohup python script.py &`) - проблем не возникало. PS как вы выходите из `screen session` (по `Ctrl+C` выходить нельзя)?

Comment: Точно уверен, там крутится flask, и он работает корректно, потому что я его запускал внутри screen и смотрел, работает ли он — все ок, и он работает, пока я не закрою консоль. Все-таки подозреваю, что это какие-то невидимые силы, связанные с осью, но пока не могу понять, какие

Comment: Попробуйте написать простой скрипт (без использования Flask), который будет писать текущее время в файл раз в 30 секунд / минуту и запустить его при помощи `screen` или `nohup ... &`, чтобы убедиться что все работает правильно и исключить "проблемы" с Flask

Comment: `... & disown` - у меня после выхода работает благополучно

Comment: ну одни процессы умеют отвязываться от управляющего терминала, а другие -- нет.